# yii gridview dropdownlist issue

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a grid which list all of the data, but the problem is what I want is when select status change to "non-active", all "non-active" should be list out with orange color as below:

[image]

Any suggestion to change it? Active actually is based on date>now() and non-active is based on date

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your GridView. You can use bootstrap colors of your choice, 'warning' gives red. If you have some other condition that qualifies your status to be 'non-active', write your if condition accordingly.

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
     'rowOptions' => function($model) {            
            if ($model->status == 'non-active') {
                return ['class' => 'warning'];
            }},
    'columns' => []
          ]);
```